# Why is the solution two an ODE where the roots of the characteristic equation is real always either zero everywhere or zero at most once?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation $ay^{\prime\prime}+by^{\prime}+y=0$. If the roots of the corresponding characteristic equation are real, why is it that a solution to the differential equation either is everywhere zero or zero at most once? I have found a solution for those with the general solution $y=c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}$, but need help with proving it for those where the roots are repeated and the general solution is 
$y=c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2te^{r_1t}$. thanks for the answers!

Comment: If you format your equations with MathJax as is the standard for this site, they likely won't be ignored for so long. Good grammar, spelling, punctuation, and capitalization and MathJax equations make it much easier for others to read your question hence more likely to provide a constructive answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}$, then if $c_1=0$ $y$ can't be $0$ unless $c_2$ is also $0$, in which case $y=0$ everywhere. Similarly, if $c_2=0$, then $y$ is either identically $0$ or never $0$. If neither $c_1$ nor $c_2$ are $0$, then if$y=c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}=0$, then $e^{(r_1-r_2)t}=-c_2/c_1$ so this can only happen when
$$t=\frac{\ln\left(-\frac{c_2}{c_1}\right)}{r_1-r_2}$$
But you've already got this part, right? Now, for repeated real roots, $y=(c_1+c_2t)e^{r_1t}$. If $c_2=0$, then $y$ can't be $0$ unless $c_1$ is also $0$, which would again make $y$ identically $0$. And if $c_2\ne0$, then if $y=(c_1+c_2t)e^{r_1t}=0$, then $t=-c_1/c_2$.